# In countable hausdorff space every one point set is g delta set

Tags: general-topology

show that in a first countable hausdorff space every one point set is g delta set?I want the proof of this above question

Comment: That's not how this site works

Comment: See the post [How to ask a good question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959), especially the section on [adding context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X = \{x_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ to  make it explicitly countable.
As $X$ is $T_1$ in particular, finite sets are closed, so all sets $U_n = X\setminus\{x_n\}$ are open. Now $$\{x_m\}  =\cap \{U_n:  n \neq m\}$$
for every $m$, making all singletons a $G_\delta$.

Note that Hausdorff is slightly overkill, only $T_1$ is used.