# show that in first countable hausdorff space every open set is G δ set?

Tags: general-topology, self-learning

This is question from my assignment i have tried to do some proof on it
Let $\{x\}$ be one point set in $X$ since $X$ is countable then there exists a countable basis for $x$ since $X$ is hausdorff for any $x,y\in X$ with $x$ not equal to $y$ there is a open set $U$ containing $x$ and $V$ containing $y$ im not able to do the proof further can u help me with this proof?

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to prove? Your title indicates that you want to prove that in any first-countable Hausdorff space every open set is G-δ (which is trivially true for _any_ space if you know what G-δ means). But the body of your question seems different. Please [edit] your question so that the title and body match.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2139379/4280 is probably what you mean?

Comment: A countable space need not have a countable local base at any point, so that's where your suggestion fails.

Comment: "since $X$ is countable".... First-countable means every point in $X$ has a countable local base. It does not mean the space is countable. The Q in the title is unprovable because there are uncountable first-countable spaces in which not every open set is $G_{\delta}.$

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing my own answer from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2139379/4280):

Suppose $X = \{x_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ to  make it explicitly countable.
As $X$ is $T_1$ in particular, finite sets are closed, so all sets $U_n = X\setminus\{x_n\}$ are open. Now $$\{x_m\}  =\cap \{U_n:  n \neq m\}$$
for every $m$, making all singletons a $G_\delta$.

Note that Hausdorff is slightly overkill, only $T_1$ is used.